# Is this a correct usage of the word "during"?

Tags: grammar

Just come across this sentence

"A good outline will guide you during you writing your novel."

It seems a little bit odd to me. I know you can phrase it like "A good outline will guide you while you're writing your novel." But is this grammatically correct?

Comment: No, it's not correct.  Hopefully it's just a typo, but if not, you might not want to take writing advice from this author.

Comment: *During your writing*, *during your novel writing*, or *during the writing of your novel* would all be fine.

Comment: I hope you didn't pay any money for this writing "advice".

Comment: Thank you guys, it's just something I pick up on during some online courses, LOL.

Comment: I'm flagging this as off-topic ("no research / ELL"). Gardness, any competent English speaker would recognise this as poor English. What research did you do before asking here? Can I recommend our sister site [ELL.SE] as a better place to look for answers on English questions that a fluent speaker would find trivial. If you have a question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not correct because "during" is a preposition.  There is no prepositional phrase following "during" in this sentence, only an independent clause which requires a conjunction.

So you could say

> "A good outline could help you **while** you are writing your novel."

or

> "A good outline could help during **the writing of your novel**."